# Display the Month and Value of the Highest Sale by Customer

Tags: looker-studio

Using Google Data Studio, I want to make a report on Highest Sale done by Each Customer with Which Month the Highest sale was done.

Pleases find below link for Google Sheet data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g20m5jVs9BX1-oCeOu_W4OUq5E2Loi-e6-XXufd7cBM/edit?usp=sharing

Using the below data I arrived the Highest sales of each customer using Max but unable to get in which month the highest sale was done.

Google Data Studio Link:
https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/45c04f04-e239-41a0-9ee4-69e0331f8d3d

```
Customer Name   Month   Sales
AA              Oct        301
BB              Apr      3,154
BB              May      3,113
BB              Jun      5,431
BB              Jul     10,185
BB              Aug      6,123
BB              Sep      3,147
BB              Oct      6,154
BB              Nov      9,818
BB              Dec      6,547
BB              Jan      6,035
BB              Feb     15,231
BB              Mar      3,719
CC              Apr     18,092
CC              May     20,926
CC              Jun     27,897
CC              Jul     23,959
CC              Aug     23,428
```

Answer (score 0):

One way that it can be achieved is by:

### 1) Chart Type

- [Pivot Table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7516660)

### 2) Fields

- ***Row Dimension #1***: `Customer Name`
- ***Row Dimension #2***: `Month`
- ***Metric***: `Sales`

### 3) Sorting

- ***Row #1***: `Customer Name`; ***Order***: Ascending; ***Number of Rows***: Auto
- ***Row #2***: `Sales`; ***Order***: Descending; ***Number of Rows***: 1

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/17ae4937-0492-40bf-b0dd-4c0b96689958) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]